# Getting an error when calling tableView reloadData: The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've seen this error before in people's questions but the only answer I've found is that I should be calling reloadData. But, that seems to be exactly when I'm getting the error!

So I have a bunch of data for a tableView in an array called itemArray. It's empty until a NSURLRequest completes and then when it returns in the number of rows in section 2 is updated to [itemArray count];

The weird thing is that the error isn't always thrown. Its very intermittent so I'm having trouble isolating what's wrong.

Anyone know a common cause of this error? I always call reloadData as soon as the datasource changes. Is there any code I can provide that might help you to help me?

**Exact error:**

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 2.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (100) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Updated. Not exactly sure what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without looking at your code, but is the itemArray initialized?  Maybe initialize it in viewDidLoad and see if the errors go away.

Comment: Yea its initialized. And anyway in the method I protect against that by using if(itemArray && itemArray.count) return itemArray.count; else return 0;

Comment: You don't need these checks. If the array is nil, the count will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` somewhere incorrectly. If you are calling `reloadData`, you should not work with the begin and end updates API.

Comment: Ive never called beginUpdates or endUpdates.

Comment: @JoshDG Well, something is calling them, and the API is complaining because it was not told about the updates properly, yet it was called.